# Where to find Apache Hive Embedded

Tags: hive

I believe Apache Hive can be embedded in Java programs. Can somebody please direct me to the page where "Embedded Hive" can be downloaded? I need to embed Hive to be able to run it on Windows, which is where I am developing my application. Further instructions for embedding and code samples will also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive supports embedded mode only in the sense that the RDBMS which stores the meta information for the Hive tables can run locally or on a stand alone server (ref https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient ). Furthermore, hive with it's accompanying database is merely an orchestrator for a string of MapReduce jobs, which requires the Hadoop framework to be running as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following class org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer.HiveServerHandler make sure that hive/conf is on the classpath. And all the hive jars from hive/lib.  This embedded client needs to be run from the same machine where your hive is installed.  If your hive-site.xml is using derby than the embedded client will create a .metastore folder, if your hive-site.xml is  using standalone db, then the embedded client will communicate with the db directly so make sure it is running.